# Jquery UI datepicker add "Unknown" option value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In Jquery UI datepicker, I would like to add an `Unknown` option to select **if user didn't know the date.** Then get that unknown option value to the input field. I tried to add it on month list dropdown but how we can get `unknown` value to the input. And also need `unknown` should be listed in year dropdown.

I don't know if that can be done. So, expect your other valuable ideas to put unknown date in the date picker. *(also welcome other datepickers..)*

Code:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "c-150:c+30",
        
        monthNames: [ "Unknown", "January","February","March","April","May","June",
   "July","August","September","October","November","December" ], 
      
  monthNamesShort: [ "UNK", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" style="width:250px" id="datepicker">
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/Lxudnpgm/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no straight forward way of accomplishing this in your script, You have a workaround to get this done,

For which, you need to download the `jquery-ui.js` from CDN (you can use the same URL given in your script) and have it stored in your scripts directory. It would be better to download all three scripts and to have them stored locally.

Then, you need to edit it where you need to add a piece of code like this,

Just before line #9037 (where you'll see a for loop for processing year), Try adding the below statement,

```
yearshtml += '<option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>'
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also have the downloaded code and it worked well under the year options. But I need to get the value to the input field..

Comment: Do you mean displaying the `Unknown` text if the user selects it in the year dropdown?